# Is anything wrong in the code

Tags: vbscript

I have a code like below. To split numbers am using the below code. Now i need to split the value stores in the MyArray

```
       <html>
    <body onload = "VerifyTimeSelectionNew();">
  <script language="VBScript">
  Const LEVEL_DATE_RANGE1 = 110
    Function VerifyTimeSelectionNew()
   'Dim cboTime
    'cboTime = document.getElementsByName("TimeDropdown:cboTime")
    'If CInt(cboTime.options(cboTime.selectedIndex).value) = LEVEL_DATE_RANGE1 Then
       Dim hdnTime
        Dim MyArray, i, newValue,value,newArray


        hdnTime="0:0:0:0:0:2:201201:201311:False:False:True:False"


          MyArray = Split(hdnTime, ":")
           For i = 0 to 3
       MsgBox (MyArray(i))
       Next

     value = MyArray(7)
      newArray = split(value ,"")

        // newValue = value.substring(0,4)

      MsgBox(newArray(0))

    End Function

     </script>

       </body>
      </html>
```

When i execute this am getting 201311. am not able to split 201311. Can u tell me y???

Comment: I don't think you can declare and assign variables as a single statement in VBScript (unlike, say, VB.Net)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks!! I have edited the script. Can u help me with this?

Comment: Please do not move the target. Your edit is an entirely different question, so you should post it as a new question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thank you so much :):). And sorry for editing on same question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code snippet.

1. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever already pointed out, you cannot define a variable and at the same time assign a value to it. VBScript only allows this for constants.
2. VBScript doesn't support defining variables as a particular type.
3. VBScript strings aren't objects, so they don't have a method `Substring()`. Use the [`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function instead.

Change these lines:

```
Dim value As String = "JohnRich"
Dim subString As String   = value.Substring(0,4)
```

into this:

```
Dim value     : value     = "JohnRich"
Dim subString : subString = Left(value, 4)
```

or this:

```
Dim value, subString

value     = "JohnRich"
subString = Left(value, 4)
```